# dynamic accordion with bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time getting this dynamic accordion to work properly.

I'm fetching accordion title from MySQL database and trying to create a dynamic accordion based on number of rows in my database.

As of right now, I'm only able to create single tab with first title in my database.

```
        <?php 

            foreach ($variable as $key); 

            ?>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" style="margin-right:50%;" > <img src="image.jpeg" class="event-icon"> <?php echo $key['title']?>;</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Event content
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to create the following html structure when the foreach loop runs.

```
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" style="margin-right:50%;" > <img src="image.jpeg" class="event-icon"> <?php echo $key['title']?>;</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Event content
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `<?php endforeach; ?>` ? (Just btw: change the `;` to `:` in your foreach header)

Comment: I'm getting PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH in everytime I add <?php endforeach; ?> after the last </div> in the second example.

Comment: Did you changed your `;` to `:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with the [alternative syntax for foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#82511)

```
foreach ($variable as $key);
```

should be

```
foreach ($variable as $key):
```

semicolon (;) should be a colon (:)

it also ends with a endforeach semicolon

```
endforeach;
```

Comment: Also he forgot a `endforeach;`

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked! really appreciate it :) have a great weekend!

Comment: @Deano Really i wrote that 14 minutes ago! And you said you get an error and now you accept this answer which even wasn't complete? (Did you read my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748424/dynamic-accordion-with-bootstrap#comment43908064_27748424 ?)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add at the end of your foreach loop, like this:

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also you have to change `;` -> `:` in your foreach header:

```
foreach ($variable as $key);
```

to:

```
foreach ($variable as $key):
                         //^See here
```